# How to see what NFTs a website visitor has in their Phantom Wallet

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I've created some NFTs on the Solana Blockchain and now have them in my Phantom Wallet.

How would I create a website that checks the users' wallet to see which NFTs they have in it, eg to make them available in a web based game I might create?

I can't see any info on this in the Phantom docs but it must be possible since sites like Solsea do this.

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't got the user to connect their wallet at this point, I would recommend the **anchor wallet library**.

Some relevent resources can be found here for actually retrieving solana nft metadata:

[Get the list of assets associated to a Solana wallet address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352688/get-the-list-of-assets-associated-to-a-solana-wallet-address)

[Code sample for parsing metadata for Solana NFT and updating the metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69152527/code-sample-for-parsing-metadata-for-solana-nft-and-updating-the-metadata)

[@solana/web3.js Is there an API for ERC721 Metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913872/solana-web3-js-is-there-an-api-for-erc721-metadata/69526205#69526205)